# Let $A = \{ r_1 r_2 e^{i\phi_3} + r_2 r_3 e^{i\phi_1} + z\,r_3 r_1 e^{i\phi_2} \} $ ,what is $A$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $A = \{ r_1 r_2 e^{i\phi_3} + r_2 r_3 e^{i\phi_1} + z\,r_3 r_1 e^{i\phi_2}  \} $

such that

$r_1,r_2,r_3\in \mathbb{R}$ and fixed, and $\phi_1 + \phi_2 + \phi_3 = 0$ and, $\left| z \right| = 1$

Can we prove that, $A$ is the  closed equilateral triangle whose vertices are the cube 
roots of z?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question?

Comment: If you allow the $r_k$ to vary then $A$ cannot be bounded... So, what is fixed and what can vary?

Comment: @lhf - I edited this post.

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566072/what-is-numerical-range-of-a/1566110?noredirect=1#comment3189895_1566110)